# Need help mysql xampp eroor

Tags: java, mysql, xampp

I need help I have a problem with xampp (more precisely mysql) I have an error I can't start it

````
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable**
**2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2022-04-06 18:12:43 0 [ERROR] Aborting**
2022-04-06 18:12:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions```
````

Comment: [XAMPP: ERROR InnoDB: The innodb_system data file 'ibdata1' must be writable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162764/xampp-error-innodb-the-innodb-system-data-file-ibdata1-must-be-writable)

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: You're most likely facing a file permission issue.

Comment: How do I set it, what I don't understand is that yesterday it was working very well

Comment: I can't assist you further without any knowledge of your current operating system!  Always endeavour to provide enough information in regards to your current working environment when asking questions.